# Probabilistic primality test that might return a prime as a composite but never a composite as prime

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, cryptography, primality-test

I am currently analyzing the AKS algorithm and I saw that for practical purpose usually only probabilistic test are used due to faster runtime. I know that the probabilities in these test can be made so small such that it becomes irrelevant for any practical application. Nevertheless I am bothered by the fact that all test seem to have their error such that they might return a composite as a prime and was wondering if anybody knows about (or if they even exist) probabilistic test that might return a prime as a composite but we can be absolutely certain that the number is prime if prime is returned? I can't seem to finde anything of that sort.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you want is a primality proof. I only know two methods that are relatively efficient in practice : The Adleman Pomerance Rumely test (APR) and Elliptic Curve Primality Proving (ECPP). But both tests are quite slow if the input has several thousand digits.

Comment: The BPSW-test is extremely reliable (NO counterexample is known). This (efficient) test seperates the primes form the composites already very very good , so a test that might return "composite" for a prime would have very little merit since almost all composite numbers are detected composite by BPSW.

Comment: [Fastest way to find if a given number is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897241/338051)